# Get the total hits each day from an access_log file via shell commands

Tags: shell, unix

I have an access_log file in this format:

```
65.175.123.152 - - [08/May/2007:02:17:40 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 217 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.0.11) Gecko/20070312 Firefox/1.5.0.11"
```

Now I want to get the amount of total hits each day using unix shell commands.

I think it has to do something with using grep, I'm new to unix so what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

For a specific day you could do something like this:

```
grep 08/May/2007 /var/log/httpd/access_log | wc -l
```

That is, find all the access log entries with the given date and then count the number of lines found.

If you are looking to produce a report of hits for each day for all days in the log:

```
awk '
  {
    when=substr($4, 2, 11);
    totals[when]++
  } 
  END {
    for (i in totals) 
      print i, totals[i]
  }' /var/log/httpd/access_log | sort
```

The result of which looks like:

```
01/Jan/2013 9
02/Jan/2013 33
03/Jan/2013 262
04/Jan/2013 35
05/Jan/2013 19
06/Jan/2013 9
07/Jan/2013 24
08/Jan/2013 68
09/Jan/2013 16
10/Jan/2013 16
```